# What units are represented by pr - micrometer?

Tags: units, atmospheric-science, solar-system, elements

In studying column abundances, I often encounter the units $pr-\mu m$. What does this stand for? Part per micrometer? how can this be an abundance unit?

Incredibility I cannot figure out what it means after quite a bit of online searching.

Comment: Likely per micrometer. The pr is not standard. I imagine it would be commonly used in display technology and micofabrication for density. In molecular fields you have the related ppm for parts per million.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it is precipitable microns (https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1029/2006JE002695)